# Find longest word in txt file with C++

Tags: c++

I have a .txt file that looks like this:

```
bear
cat
wolf
mouse
tiger
elephant
rat
```

I need to write a simple loop that reads my txt file and outputs the longest word. How would I go about this?

Edit The problem I am having is going through each line in the file.

```
biggestword="o";

while (i=0;i<linesinfile;i++) {
    if (currentword.length>biggestword.length) {
        biggestword = currentword;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I wrote dummy code but I'm not sure how to implement what I want.

Comment: Man. SO is not a code service. Try to solve it on your own. Ask here about a defined point in your code.

Comment: Well, simply read each word into a separate string and then use the standard library to get the length of each string. Compare the lengths.

Comment: you can easily achieve that by using `std::fstream`, `std::string` and a `while` loop

Comment: Edit your question. Don't dump your code in comment.

Comment: There are many C++ tutorials that explain how to read files. SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: Use `istream& getline (istream& is, string& str)`. You can `std::ifstream file("filename.txt"); while (std::getline(file, currentword)) { /* your code */ }`

Comment: Hint: `while (i=0;i<linesinfile;i++)` is not valid. Perhaps you prefer `for` instead of `while`

Answer (score 3):

Open the file with

```
std::ifstream file("filename.txt");
```

and read each line with

```
while (std::getline(file, currentword)) { /* your code */ }
```